# How to display beamer toc in appendix?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, texstudio, appendices

I am creating a beamer for a final exam project. Once I'm writing after 
`\appendix`, `\tableofcontents` won't appear. Any help here please?

TOC in introduction frame only shows sections and subsections, how can I also make appear subsubsections in TOC only in appendix frames?

Thank you a lot!

PS: I am using metropolistheme :)

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} 

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \section{B}
    \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please make [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: sure, there you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Normally beamer treats the appendix as a separate part. You can trick it by decreasing the part counter.
- To hide `subsubsections` from one of toc, you could use `subsubsectionstyle=hide`.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme 

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
        \subsection{sub}
        \subsubsection{subsub}
        \begin{frame}
        content...
        \end{frame}        
    \section{B}
    \subsection{sub}
    \subsubsection{subsub}
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide]
        \end{frame}

\appendix
\addtocounter{part}{-1}
\begin{frame}
        appendix
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```